# Spring 3.0 and SOAP - What's best practice?

Tags: web-services, spring, soap, jakarta-ee, struts2

I'm reimplementing a web app in Spring, and I need to expose the business logic with SOAP. I'm going for Spring 3.0, and I'd like to know: what is the recommended way of exposing Spring beans? The rest of my stack is Tomcat 6, JDK 1.6, Struts 2.

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Spring WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/index.html) if you are using Spring 3.  The Spring folks prefer contract first web services which is outlined in the tutorial.

Alternately, [Jersey-WS](http://jersey.java.net/) is really good for REST based web services.

Comment: I understand that REST APIs are included with Spring 3, so I'd rather use what comes with it. Will Spring WS be compatible with "the Spring 3 way"?

Comment: No, not exactly.  Going over Spring 3 REST again, that looks pretty compelling too.  It depends on if you want contract first or not - I never would - if not, use the Spring 3 REST implementation if it's working properly (it's not released yet as far as I know).

Comment: We use the REST stuff in Spring 3 Milestone 3, and it works perfectly. Much nicer than JAX-RS. Oh, and +1 for Spring-WS - this is the way that SOAP should be done, and it integrates perfectly with the Spring 2.5-style annotated controller pattern.

Comment: I'll build my REST interface from the ground up, but my SOAP interface needs to conform to an already defined WSDL since I'm rebuilding a SOAP interface to work with my Spring logic rather than the deprecated .Net project it precedes. So I'm contract first when it comes to the SOAP interface. So what I hear you say is: (1) Use Spring 3 for REST, (2) Use Spring WS with Spring 3 for SOAP. Correct?

Comment: I think skaffman should post a Spring 3 REST answer here and I should build something concrete with it.

Comment: @niklassaers: yes, that would be my recommendation.